Is there any way to modification on chunk sequence for file
I am Using ng2-pdf-viewer package to view pdf file.
It is working fine for small sized documents and it's not taking much time to show to user,
but when it comes to large file PDF which is Linearized as well causing to much time to show to user.
what i observed that while making chunk call first partial call gets range with 0-1MB,
but very next partial call sends request for near about last 1Mb range.
my guessing that due to those chunk sequence Linearization is not working properly for ng2-pdf-viewer.
is there any way we can make partial calls in sequence from configuration based?
i found range we can pass which is the instance of PDFDataRangeTransport but there isn't any document or way i found to work with?
Any observation or help is appreciated form the community.
Thanks

@KJ i have seen the demo of Apryse same file working in it properly but not in ng2-pdf-viewer so i asked a question if any one have any idea for the package, also i'm trying for another open source PDF viewer which is ngx-extended-pdf-viewer.
